# async.series inside an asynchronous grunt task

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, gruntjs, npm

I have a grunt tasks which runs asynchronously (using this.async) as I have asynchronous functions in the code. I also want few tasks to run in series so I am using async.series from async npm module. 
Problem is that when I reach the last callback of async.series i.e. function(err, result), I call a done() to inform that the asynchronous grunt task has been successfully completed, it fails sometimes and passes sometimes. I cannot seem to understand it. Here is the code:

```
grunt.registerTask('aggCompJSON', function(){
  var done = this.async();
  var resultFile = {};  // final JSON object
  var groupJSON = {};   // groups JSON object

  async.series([
    function(callback){
        // get Application Configuration
        __getAppConfig(grunt, callback);
    },

    function(callback){
        // generate Component_map
        __genCompMap(grunt, callback);
    }
  ], function (err, result){
        done();
    }
  );
```

I get the following error:

> Fatal error: ENOENT, open 'logs/app.log'

and also sometimes a success. Any input is appreciated. 
Thanks

> P.S. None of the functions return error. The **err** object in the
>   last callback is always **null**.

Comment: Why does `__genCompMap` need two callbacks: `done` and `callback`?

Comment: You are right. There's no need for that. I had changed the logic and forgot to remove it. I have updated the code. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Are you catching the errors when they happen and passing them as the first arguments of the callback functions? If you don't do this, `async.series` won't know that an error happened.

Comment: Yes! Whenever there's an error, I call the callback with an error. The weird part is that it fails sometimes and successfully runs at other times.

Comment: Could you please post the contents of the function that returns the error?

Comment: None of the private functions return an error. The call to **done()** inside the last callback i.e. function (err, result) returns an error.

Comment: Ok. Then, based on the error message, somewhere you're (or grunt is) trying to open a file that doesn't exist yet. Maybe the step responsible for creating the file has not finished when some further step tries to open it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help @RodrigoMedeiros. Yes you were right, I was trying to  **require** a module in one of the functions and it was behaving unexpectedly. The fix is to just check what statements might cause errors because of asynchronous execution of grunt task. In my case I removed those statements, they were unnecessary.